# Error running Griffon app in IntelliJ, but it works from command prompt

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, griffon

There's an exercise with mortageCalc application at paragraph 3.6.1 in the [Griffon in Action](http://www.manning.com/almiray/) book.

Environment:

- Win 7 Pro, 64-bit
- IntelliJ IDEA ver 12.1
- Griffon-1.2.0 JDK 1.6

I have **MortgageCalView**:

```
package mortgagecal

application(title:'Mortgage Calculator', pack:true, locationByPlatform:true)
        {
            panel(border: emptyBorder(6)) {
                gridLayout(rows:4, columns:2, hgap:6, vgap:6)
                label('Principal:')
                textField(text: bind(target:model, 'principal',
                        value:'$200,000',
                        validator: model.validatePrincipal,
                        converter: model.convertPrincipal))
                label('Interest Rate:')
                textField(text: bind(target:model, 'monthlyRate',
                        value:'6.5%',
                        validator: model.validateRate,
                        converter: model.convertRate))
                label('Term:')
                textField(text: bind(target:model, 'months',
                        value:'30',
                        validator: model.validateTerm,
                        converter: model.convertTerm))
                label('Monthly Payment (P&I):')
                textField(editable:false,
                        text: bind(source: model, sourceProperty: 'payment',
                                sourceEvent: 'propertyChange',
                                converter: model.convertPayment))
            }
        }
```

and **MortgageCalModel**:

```
package mortgagecal

import groovy.beans.Bindable
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.text.DecimalFormat

@Bindable
class MortgageCalModel {
    float principal
    float monthlyRate
    float months
    float getPayment() {
        return principal * monthlyRate /
                (1-Math.pow(1/(1+monthlyRate),months))
    }
    private currencyFormat = NumberFormat.currencyInstance
    private percentFormat = new DecimalFormat('0.00%')
    def validatePrincipal = {
        try {
            float principal = currencyFormat.parse(it)
            return principal > 0
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false
        }
    }
    def convertPrincipal = currencyFormat.&parse
    def validateRate = {
        try {
            float rate = percentFormat.parse(it)
            return rate > 0 && rate < 0.30
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false
        }
    }
    def convertRate = {
        return percentFormat.parse(it) / 12
    }
    def validateTerm = {
        try {
            def term = Float.parseFloat(it)
            return term > 0 && term < 100
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false
        }
    }
    def convertTerm = {
        return Float.parseFloat(it) * 12
    }
    def convertPayment = {
        return currencyFormat.format(it)
    }
}
```

When run it, I see errors:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   mortgagecal.MortgageCalView.application() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap,
>   mortgagecal.MortgageCalView$_run_closure1) values: [[title:Mortgage
>   Calculator, pack:true, locationByPlatform:true], ...]
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   mortgagecal.MortgageCalView.application() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap,
>   mortgagecal.MortgageCalView$_run_closure1) values: [[title:Mortgage
>   Calculator, pack:true, locationByPlatform:true], ...]     at
>   mortgagecal.MortgageCalView.run(MortgageCalView.groovy:3)

But, when I run in command prompt, it works fine:

```
cd D:\work\griffon\mortgageCal> 
griffon run-app
```

So, there's smth wrong with my IntelliJ...

Comment: If I do: `griffon create-app mortgageCalc`, then `cd mortgageCalc` then paste those two files into the model and view class, it works fine for me...

Comment: @tim_yates thanks. I've just confirmed it works fine when I run from command prompt, so I've just edited my question.

Comment: Be sure to invoke the following command (from the commandline) when using IntelliJ and Griffon:  griffon integrate-with --idea

This command generates IDEA project files with full dependency information.

Comment: @aalmiray on the 51th page of the book, it says to use "--intellij"

Comment: You can use either --idea or --intellij, both are supported :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solved!*
The reason why it was giving an error, because I was trying to run **MortgageCalView.groovy**.
When I run **Griffon: mortgageCal** it worked. :) In other words: I had to run the project, not a particular script.

Comment: Ah yes. clicking on the default run configuration will invoke the run-app command on the project itself.